# Font-weight less than 400 on inputs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a font-weight of 300 for my site, and the text inside an input refuses to go thinner than 400. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/m8FZ6/3/

```
<span style="font-weight: 300;">300 weight:</span> <input type="text" value="text" style="font-weight: 300;"></input><br />
<span style="font-weight: 400;">400 weight:</span> <input type="text" value="text" style="font-weight: 400;"></input><br />
<span style="font-weight: 700;">700 weight:</span> <input type="text" value="text" style="font-weight: 700;"></input>
```

I've noticed this in FF 25, Chrome 30.0.1599.69, and IE10. Is there a way to make it work, or will I have to use a different element?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`input` elements (and others like `textarea`, etc.) do not inherit font from the parent element. They have their own default fonts.

If you change your CSS selector to `html, input`, you can see it has the appropriate font weight in all inputs.

Comment: Note that some browsers let inputs inherit some properties. For instance, Opera v12 inherits the font-style. That is, if the span is italic, so is the input. Not in most other browsers though.

Comment: The thing that was throwing me off was that 700 worked. Of course, my default font supports bold, but not 300, so that explains that.

Answer (score 4):

you need to explicitly set the font family for input boxes

http://jsfiddle.net/m8FZ6/5/

```
input {font-family: 'Roboto';}
```

Comment: You mean "explicity" ;)

Comment: IT HAS BEEN A LONG WEEK